# Topological Hausdorff space that is completely regular is equivalent to the convergence of nets

Tags: general-topology, nets

I'm reading a book, where there is the following theorem:
Let $X$ be a topological Hausdorff space. Then the statements are equivalent:

(a) $X$ is completely regular.

(b) A net $\{x_i\}$ in $X$ converges to $x$ if and only if $f(x_i) \to f(x)$ for each continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$.

From the proof in the book it is clear, that $(a) \implies (b)$, but i think the direction $(b) \implies (a)$ is left out or i just don't get the argument. Could someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: Maybe you should add some kind of reference to the book you are talking about, my oracle is in for repair at the moment.

Comment: It is the book "A Course in Point Set Topology" from "John B. Conway". The theorem is "Theorem 3.2.10" on page 82.

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is not completely regular, then there is a point $x$ and an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, such that for any continuous map $f:X\to[0,1]$, no open neighborhood $V$ around $f(x)$ has its preimage in $U$, or, in other words, the closed set $A:=X\setminus U$ has points mapped to $V$ for any $V$ around $f(x)$.

Now we can construct a net $\Phi:\{V\text{ open}\mid f(x)\in V\}\to X $ such that $f(Φ)\to f(x)$ but $Φ\not\to x$, by choosing for each neighborhood $V$ around $f(x)$ a point $Φ(V)\in A\cap f^{-1}(V)$.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Unfortunately, I still don't understand it. We have defined "completely regular" like this: A topological Space $X$ is called completely regular, if for every closed subset $F \subset X$ and for every $x \in X \backslash F$ there is a continuous function $f: X \to [0,1]$, such that $f(x) = 1$ and $f(y) = 0$ for every $y \in F$. So if we assume that $X$ is not completely regular and $f$ is a continuous function $X \to [0,1]$, $U$ a neighbourhood of $x$, why is $f^{-1}(V) \not\subset U$ for every neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$?

Comment: @AlexS: There are various characterizations for complete regularity. For example: The preimages $f^{-1}(V)$ of all open sets in $\Bbb R$ under all real-valued maps $f$ on $X$ form a base for the topology on $X$. That's what I used in my post. It also doesn't matter in all these characterizations if you consider maps to $\Bbb R$ or maps to $[0,1]$.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I didn't know this definition you mentioned. Would it be possible to write down a proof of $(b) \implies (a)$ using the definition I mentioned? How would you do that?